# Comparing strings in a Magento .phtml file

Tags: php, html, string, magento

i am working with magento and i want to show one div, depending if i am in a specific view. I use the following:

```
<?php
   $url1 = (string)$this->getBaseUrl()."home_tienda";
   $url2 = (string)$this->getUrl('*/*/*',array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
?>
```

If i type a "var_dump" of $url1 and $url2, i obtain the following:

```
string(28) "http://127.0.0.1/home_tienda"
string(37) "http://127.0.0.1/home_tienda"
```

Well, i have tried this:

```
<?php if (strcmp($url1,$url2)==0):?>
<div class="clsbanner"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_banner')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif?>
```

and i have tried this too:

```
<?php if ($url1==$url2):?>
<div class="clsbanner"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_banner')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif?>
```

in both i obtained false, so my div doesnt show, and i need it to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please retry `strcmp()` and/or `stricmp()` with the `===` operator. Another useful tool is `stripos()`, which returns 0 from your URL comparison but will return FALSE if string isn't found.

`0 == FALSE` tests the same...

However

`0 === FALSE` will catch the condition you are looking for as `===` matches data type as well.